# Issue for upgrading php version (5.5.38) to latest version 7.3 in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am going to upgrade my php version from `5.5.38` to `7.3.8`.
My current Codeigniter version is `2.1.0` and mysql version: `5.7.17` *MySQL Community Server (GPL)*
I don't want to change Codeigniter version (`2.1.0`) but want to upgrade    the php version.
Could any one tell me what kind of issue I will face and the precaution I should take.
Please help.

Comment: You can check this link might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037434/codeigniter-compatibility-with-php-version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48639870/2139772

Comment: if i were you. i'd download xampp for your new php version and see any issues that may occur .

Comment: You may get some undefined error in php because some functions has been deleted in php 7 . That means there are difference between php 5 and 7. 
i always recommend you to upgrade your codeigniter framework version as latest version always supports, ensures security .