# CodeIgniter error "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings."

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, codeigniter-2

I've just started work on an old CI project with a lot of old code. The application works fine on the server, but when I pull it to my local environment (it's also in a github repository), I get the "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings." error. I have a few other CodeIgniter projects that work just fine locally. I've also tried using the database I'm trying to connect to with another application and it connects normally.

I've tried the solutions on a few other answers like changing the driver to mysqli (it was already set as mysqli) and changing the socket in php.ini but they don't seem to work for me.

The database.php file:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'testdatabase';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I'm running CodeIgniter v2.2.0, XAMPP with phpmyadmin v4.9.0.1, Apache 2.4.4.1 and PHP 7.1.32

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48639870/2275490

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'testdatabase',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Try this config.