# Problem in setting up a running Codeigniter 2.1.4 project with PHP 7.3.9 in localhost Xampp

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I open http://localhost/MyPrjectName I get these errors:

[image: click here] see the attached screenshot.

I am using codeigniter 2.1.4 and php 7.3.9 on Xampp

And my .htaccess has the code below:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myprojectname.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myprojectname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
        ErrorDocument 404 http://www.myprojectname.com/


        #Removes access to the system folder by users.
        #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
        #previously this would not have been possible.
        #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
        #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
        #Submitted by: Fabdrol
        #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
        #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
        #request to index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

    </IfModule>
```

What can I do to fix this error ?

Comment: Tell us what errors you are getting

Comment: you can see attached screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adm2b.png for error. but i am facing this when i have removed .htaccess from my project

Comment: @vikek: Thanks. Can you please write the errors down? Its better to write it down. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting errors below:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 257

404 
OOPS! Page Not Found.
Sorry but we couldn't find the page you are looking for. Please
check to make sure you've typed the URL correctly.

Comment: you are using a non supported CI version, please read: [CodeIgniter compatibility with PHP version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037434/codeigniter-compatibility-with-php-version#41040062)

Comment: This is not a problem with .htaccess. If it was then the file Common.php would probably not be executed, but it clearly is executed. The error is probably in your controller though it might be because CodeIgniter is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For php error See here, for reference
[Only variable references should be returned by reference - Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter)

Update your .htaccess for localhost server

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /MyProjectName/$1 [L,R=301]
    ErrorDocument 404 /MyProjectName
</IfModule>
```